# What is more efficient in ConstraintLayout: 230dp of Layout margin or using a new guideline?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am using a ConstraintLayout and I want to make the following constraint:

[image]

I have made it using a lot of margin and also using a guideline. I would like to know which situation is more efficient:

**Situation 1** using layout_marginEnd(230dp):

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" 
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="230dp"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Situation 2** using GuideLine:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view1"
            />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.44" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which situation is better for performance and it will be better to use, situation one with almost 250dp of layout_marginEnd or situation 2 with a vertical guideline?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Performance differences between these will be near non-existent but Guideline is the better choice because `230dp` is absolute meanwhile guideline has a percentage so the UI will stay more consistent across more devices.

Comment: More Consistent here is a bit of a stretch (no pun intended). It really depends on what the OP needs. Performance wise, I'd expect these to be within less than a millisecond of difference (if any!). If your 230 came from "observing" that in your particular device where you did this calculation the distance was adequate, then the guideline with % is more appropriate, since the 230dp may look differently in different densities/screen sizes. But... on the other hand, NN percent of one screen can also mean a different thing in a completely different device/density.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Now I'm more confused between whether to choose guideline or margin hahaha. I thought that using Constraint Layout was a way to save all the proportions of the different constraints to look the same in all devices....

Comment: So if the margin will make that the constraint will look different in different screen sizes, it is not a good option, right? I thought that the dp would save the same proportions in all screen sizes since it is working with desnisty pixels...

Comment: I'd say in your example there's not a big difference, but this is something you can quickly test. You can likely even see this in the visual editor using the different device previews. Have you tried that to observe the differences?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that Margin and guideline are just for critical conditions

If you want exact position like in pic then just remove end end constraint from textview and make your textview wrap content thats all

Comment: for view if you use marginStart of 5-10 dp Thats ok but marginEnd for textview have no point

Comment: And what happens if/when the text doesn't fit in the space? What behavior would you expect there? Use either a margin or a guideline if you need to ensure certain constrains. Not using either, would mean they are not constraining the text anywhere, so it would go over other views or wrap behave in an "unconstrained" way, which may not be what the OP/Specs require.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini so removing end constraint wouldn't be a good option because it could constraint to whatever as it is not defined, right?

Comment: if you wrap a text view with no end constrain, the text has no constrain/rule to decide when to stop. So yes.